# Django - Models FK/many2many relationships

Tags: django, many-to-many, relationship, reverse

I need to understand a bit better how do FK/m2m relationships work.
I've prepared Images model for uploading images and it has an additional feature - it can be categorized by adding to a specific gallery (m2m relation to gallery).

To access gallery name I just had to do a query set for example:

```
Images.objects.filter(gallery__gallery_name = '')
```

I'd like to reverse the query a little bit so from Gallery model I can access pictures which are in specific gallery (gallery_name).

How I can do that?

Models:

```
class Images(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=update_filename, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Obrazek")
   gallery = models.ForeignKey('Gallery', blank=True, null=True)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    gallery_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    gallery_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

View:

```
def index(request):
    p = Gallery.objects.filter(gallery_name="main").order_by('-id')
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'gallery.html', 
                                    {'gallery': p,
                                    },)
```

Template:

```
{% for n in gallery.all %}
<h2 class="center">{{n.gallery_name}}</h2>
<hr>
    {% for n in gallery.images_set %}
       <div class="grid_4">
        {{ n.image }}
       </div>
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
# models.py
class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    images = models.ManyToMany(Image)

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=SOMEPLACE_FOR_MEDIA)
```

From here you should be able to do things like:

```
image = Image.objects.get(title="Girl Holding Cheese")
related_galleries = image.gallery_set.all()
```

or something similar as needed to pull what you want. The same goes the other way. To pull all images in a gallery you would do

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.get(name="Cheesy Wimmin")
related_images = gallery.images.all()
```

Though the assignments at the end aren't necessary, I usually just pass gallery.images.all() or image.gallery_set.all() directly. Note the "_set" at the end of the reference from the object that does *not* contain the M2M definition.

On the subject of direct usage, you can do compound references like

```
Image.objects.get(title="Girl Holding Cheese").gallery_set.all()
```

as well, but you have to decide when this makes code more clear and concise and when it just makes it more confusing to read later.

I hope this put you in the right direction.

### Update

In your comment below you noticed that you cannot do

```
images = Images.objects.filter(gallery_set="Cheesy Wimmins")
related_galleries = images.gallery_set.all()
```

This is because you would be trying to filter() or all() on a queryset, not an individual model. So to make this work you can use a for loop in your template. Something like

```
# views.py
galleries = Gallery.objects.all()
return render(request, 'some/template.html', {'galleries': galleries})
```

And then

```
<!-- templates/some/template.thml -->
{% for gallery in galleries %}
    <div class="gallery">
    <h2>{{ gallery.name }}</h2>
    {% for item in gallery.images.all %}
        <div class="image">
            {{ item.image }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

or something like this. Of course, you need to do whatever formatting steps you want to make this look right, but that's a way to get at your data.

Comment: Thanks so much for help. That solved my problems :) and I get the idea now (I suppose ;) ).

Comment: Just play with it, both on the Python shell, in views and calling from templates different ways to see what makes most sense for you. 90% of Django is learnable through just screwing around with ideas once you really "get" them. Also, look in psql and see how things are arranged now if you're not familiar with database concepts.

Comment: I am playing with it right now and I've noticed that methods that do not return querysets (like get()) wont actually work. 

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'images'

So for example something like that wont work
gallery = Gallery.objects.filter(name='test').images.all()

While this works:
gallery = Gallery.objects.get(id=1).images.all() 


I still need a hint how to iterate trough the data so I can fetch more results.

Comment: Another thing to point out: I'm very specific about plural and singular in here. images is always a set, image is always an individual model. The same thing with when I define models: they are always singular, though attributes/member variables may be plural if they represent a set of data (FK or M2M).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `{% for n in gallery.images_set %}` bit in your template. `images_set` is a related manager, not a queryset. To get a queryset, you need to call `all` or another of the DBAPI methods that return querysets. So, just change it to `gallery.images_set.all`, and you're good.

Comment: Hm.. It does not seem to work for me. I still  might need some more hints and help to practice and get the idea how does that work.

{% for n in gallery.all %}
<h2 class="center">{{n.gallery_name}}</h2>
<hr>
{% for x in gallery.images_set.all %}
 <div class="grid_4">
  {{ x.image }}
 </div>
{% endfor%}

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

`gallery` is a `QuerySet` - it doesn't have a `images_set`.

This is where naming your variables more appropriately can easily start preventing these problems: for example, `galleries` would be more appropriate for a list of Gallery objects... then, `galleries.images_set` would immediately raise red flags.

Anyways, you need to call `images_set` on what you've called `n`

```
{% for n in gallery.all %}
<h2 class="center">{{n.gallery_name}}</h2>
<hr>
    {% for n in n.images_set.all %} 
       <div class="grid_4">
        {{ n.image }}
       </div>
{% endfor%}
```